# How to most compactly define addition, a norm, and a metric in this space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I have a vector space with some unusual equivalences between vectors, and I'm struggling to define a norm and metric which will preserve those equivalences in a simple way.
The way I need to represent it for my application is as a 4xN matrix of nonnegative real numbers. For simplicities sake, I will say N = 2 in this part of the explanation for simplicity's sake, but it's really in the double digits. **EDIT: Furthermore, each column of this matrix must have at least one entry which is equal to 0.**

Adding two elements of this vector space is done by first adding up the matrices in the normal way. Then for each column, you subtract the minimum value of the column from each entry. For example:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4   \\
0 & 1   \\
1  & 0    \\
2 & 3  
\end{pmatrix} +\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1   \\
1 & 2  \\
0  & 4   \\
5 & 0  
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
5-1 & 5-3   \\
1-1 & 3-3  \\
1-1  & 4-3   \\
7-1 & 3-3  
\end{pmatrix}= 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2   \\
0 & 0  \\
0  & 1   \\
6 & 0  
\end{pmatrix}$$

This addition is commutative, associative, and implies an obvious identity matrix (the zero matrix). Further, there exists an additive inverse, taken by finding a matrix which will sum with the matrix to make each column zero. For example:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4   \\
0 & 1   \\
1  & 0    \\
2 & 3  
\end{pmatrix} \implies -A =  \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0   \\
3 & 3   \\
2  & 4    \\
1 & 1  
\end{pmatrix}, A+(-A) = \begin{pmatrix}
3-3 & 4-4   \\
3-3 & 4-4   \\
3-3  & 4-4   \\
3-3 & 4-4
\end{pmatrix}$$

Scalar multiplication works the same as it does for matrices. Therefore, this defines a vector space of matrices where the entries of each matrix are nonnegative real numbers.

In theory, I could define sizes and distances for these matrices using any L-norm I please, but this doesn't preserve some of the weird equivalence properties I need. Take N=3. The following elements need to be considered equal:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4 & 2  \\
0 & 1  & 1 \\
1  & 0  & 0  \\
2 & 3 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 3 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 4 & 3 
\end{pmatrix} $$

As well as the following two elements:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 4 & 2  \\
0 & 1  & 1 \\
0  & 0  & 0  \\
0 & 3 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2 & 0 \\
1  & 1 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 0  \\
3 & 5 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$

And the following two elements:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 4 & 2  \\
0 & 1  & 1 \\
0 & 0  & 0  \\
0 & 3 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 5 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 4 
\end{pmatrix} $$

But THESE elements would NOT be eqivalent:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4 & 2  \\
0 & 1  & 1 \\
1  & 0  & 0  \\
2 & 3 & 5
\end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
5 & 3 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 4 & 3 
\end{pmatrix} $$

Essentially, rotating the matrix representations 180 degrees and moving columns forward or backward while preserving the rest of the matrix should be considered equal.

I am trying to define a norm and metric which will make the distances between these equivalent matrices zero while also trying to make UNequal different matrices.

I defined a set of metrics that would do this for differing numbers of zero columns: basically, you take the minimum of some L-metric of matrices with different columns corresponding, padding with zero columns as necessary. For example, the distance between:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 4 & 2  \\
0 & 1  & 1 \\
0  & 0  & 0  \\
0 & 3 & 5
\end{pmatrix} \text{and} \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2 & 0 \\
1  & 1 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 0  \\
3 & 5 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ is equivalent to the distance between:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 4 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 5 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \text{and} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 4 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1  & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0  & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 3 & 5 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

This makes their equality more obvious.

However, this doesn't solve the rotation equivalence issue. I could try doing it again with rotations of the matrices as well, but this doesn't solve a more annoying issue: it's an unusually cumbersome way to calculate any distances I might care about. Is there a better way to create a metric for this space, ideally in a way which induces a norm?

**EDIT 2:** user1551 pointed out to me that, with the weird equality requirements, the way I originally defined addition on this space doesn’t actually fulfill the vector space axioms. Is there a way to modify the addition operations to actually fulfill the addition axioms and then create a norm and metric which works for this? If there’s a way to biject this to a different space and then define the addition, multiplication, metric, and norm THERE instead, that is also acceptable.

Comment: I don't believe that addition has the properties you claim. For example, isn't it clear that $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$?  If so then $0$ is not the identity...

Comment: (1,1) is not a valid element of this vector space. The minimum is 1, so when you subtract 1 from both elements of the vector, it collapses to (0,0). I'll edit this to make it clearer.

Comment: When you identify a matrix $A$ with the matrix $B$ obtained by permuting its rows and columns, the set of matrices is no longer a vector space. In particular,  the identification $A=B$ should imply that $A-B=0$, but the latter in general is not true.

Comment: Even though it’s not a random permutation? Like, you can’t arbitrarily permutations the matrix throughout: the equivalent matrices are only those which are rotated

Comment: Take the first example from your question. You wrote
$$
\pmatrix{3&4&2\\ 0&1&1\\ 1&0&0\\ 2&3&5}
=\pmatrix{5&3&2\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&1&0\\ 2&4&3}.
$$
However, if $A-B$ means $A+(-B)$, then
$$
\pmatrix{3&4&2\\ 0&1&1\\ 1&0&0\\ 2&3&5}
-\pmatrix{5&3&2\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&1&0\\ 2&4&3}
=\pmatrix{3&4&2\\ 0&1&1\\ 1&0&0\\ 2&3&5}
+\pmatrix{0&1&1\\ 5&4&2\\ 4&3&3\\ 3&0&0}
=\pmatrix{0&2&0\\ 2&2&0\\ 2&0&0\\ 2&0&2}\ne0.
$$
So, we have an example where $A=B$ but $A-B\ne0$.

Comment: *headdesk*. Yes, thank you. I’m going to edit the question to ask it in a way that’s more well posed

Comment: You do not tell us why you need this to be a vector space. That is, why do you need to add two matrices? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Does the norm have to require that $|A-B|=0$ if $A\equiv B$? If so, it might be better to define a seminorm, instead of a regular norm. This relaxes the requirement that $|X|=0$ implies $X=0$. This would then enable much of the kind of activity that would normally be done with norms. This would also produce a pseudometric.

Comment: @Somos The addibility of the matrices is important because this is a set of parameters that needs to have a notion of splitting and joining: basically, if I don't have a determined way to infer how two matrices join or split, the parameters can't function in context.

Comment: @GlenO A seminorm might possibly be usable as long as it doesn't put TOO many different parameter sets as having zero distance from one another.